# expandActionView in onCreateOptionsMenu removes or hides other menu items from action bar permanently

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I have a `searchView` in action bar and when user has query in `searchView` and then rotates the device i set query in `searchView` in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and expand `searchView` with `menuItem.expandActionView()` because `searchView.setIconified(false)` has no effect for me but calling `menuItem.expandActionView()` removes or hides other menu items **even after user closes searchView other menu items remains hidden!! after searcheView closed by user even searchView icon is not showing in action bar** other menu item and `serachView` has `showAsAction` set to `ifRoom`

i am surprised as when user expands action view by clicking the search icon there is no problem but when i call `expandActionView` i have this problem !

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchMenuItem);
    searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);// <-- this line has no effect even when using false !!

    if(initialQuery != null) {

        searchView.setIconified(false);// <-- this line has no effect !!!

        searchView.setQuery(initialQuery, true);
        searchMenuItem.expandActionView();//<-- this line expands searchView but hides other menu items!!
        searchView.setQuery(initialQuery, true);
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution that i have used and is working for me is to use `always` or `never` instead of `ifRoom` for `showAsAction`

Comment: This works. But there's warning to replace with ifRoom in android studio